# Running into problems with Android OSes in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, android-x86

I've tried most of the popular Android OSes on VirtualBox, I'm only using VirtualBox because my laptop absolutely hates having any other system than Windows 10 on it. These are my results:

PrimeOS: It installs fine, but when I unmount the ISO it gives me an error

fatal no bootable medium found system halted

PhoenixOS, BlissOS: They're both hit or miss. Usually gives me the below error upon trying to format the disk

unable to mount /dev/sda1/

When they do hit, they display a [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVOmI.png) and it sticks like that, basically forever.

Android x86: It installs very well, and unmounts without a hitch, but when rebooting into the OS it just displays the [the terminal screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEDUN.png) and nothing happens.

I can post more info on my laptop if necessary, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post test as text.

Comment: Do you mean the error codes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say ‘‘please post *text* as text’’, and I’m referring to all the text in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVOmI.png).